Run time error problem1: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'
I have built chat with pdf app using  python
I want the solution , i have used some environment like stramlit, pydotenv, pyPDF2 , Google Gemini API
Title: How to resolve RuntimeError: "There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'"?
Question: I'm encountering a RuntimeError in my Python script with the message "There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'". This issue seems to be related to asyncio or threading. Can anyone provide insights into what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? I'd appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!

Welcome to stackoverflow!  I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Build a chat function?
Please provide some code. This will help others to better understand what you have done and where you need help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
